# Spark: How to structure a series of side effect actions inside mapping transformation to avoid repetition?

Tags: email, apache-spark, spark-streaming, map-function

I have a spark streaming application that needs to take these steps:

1. Take a string, apply some map transformations to it
2. Map again: If this string (now an array) has a specific value in it, immediately send an email (or do something OUTSIDE the spark environment)
3. collect() and save in a specific directory
4. apply some other transformation/enrichment
5. collect() and save in another directory.

As you can see this implies to lazily activated calculations, which do the OUTSIDE action twice. I am trying to avoid caching, as at some hundreds lines per second this would kill my server.
Also trying to mantaining the order of operation, though this is not as much as important: Is there a solution I do not know of?

EDIT: my program as of now:

```
kafkaStream;
lines = take the value, discard the topic;
lines.foreachRDD{
    splittedRDD = arg.map { split the string };
    assRDD = splittedRDD.map { associate to a table };
    flaggedRDD = assRDD.map { add a boolean parameter under a if condition + send mail};
    externalClass.saveStaticMethod( flaggedRDD.collect() and save in file);
    enrichRDD = flaggedRDD.map { enrich with external data };
    externalClass.saveStaticMethod( enrichRDD.collect() and save in file);
}
```

I put the saving part after the email so that if something goes wrong with it at least the mail has been sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final 2 methods I found were these:

1. In the DStream transformation before the side-effected one, make a copy of the Dstream: one will go on with the transformation, the other will have the `.foreachRDD{ outside action }`. There are no major downside in this, as it is just one RDD more on a worker node.
2. Extracting the `{outside action}` from the transformation and mapping the already sent mails: filter if mail has already been sent. This is a almost a superfluous operation as it will filter out all of the RDD elements.
3. Caching before going on (although I was trying to avoid it, there was not much to do)

If trying to not caching, solution 1 is the way to go